# Python2 and Python3 DPKT appears to return different output formats

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, pcap, dpkt

The DPKT library says it supports Python3 now, but it has different behavior when I use it in Python 2.x vs 3.x.  Although, both are incorrect it appears.

For example, in Python 2.x, the example given [here](https://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2008/10/15/dpkt-tutorial-2-parsing-a-pcap-file/)

```
with open('test.pcap') as f:
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
    for ts, buf in pcap:
       eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
       print eth
```

Returns a format that I don't expect, an object similar to:

```
   ^����6#���l�m�
Q!6�(�����k����~�pO���o���N�l   �k4�'���8�9�j��@mf���5��pB�6bٌ�~p��Jf.Jܼ3H�:�ݭ�k-O7+�O��
4�(�9��^F�fb��V��t˜������\�X1��#�.�ج<�Q�!����>�^ɹDĀ�orC=bC���S�6;��SR�`�� �

ZD����j2Q���m����h��)1@��1���aw}�d�ڧn�                                          ��
0Z:�`8ຄE(�@4���}������Mu��63fP�/�
������h'7�h'7�;������
```

However, in Python 3, I'm forced to open the pcap file in 'rb' mode, which is fine, except for the output issues (I'm not sure 'rb' has anything to do with the issues now):

```
with open('test.pcap', 'rb') as f:
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
    for ts, buf in pcap:
       eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
       print eth
```

This now returns what I believe is a bytestring, and I haven't found a way to get the data out of this that I need.  For example, if I needed the number of flags, I can easily get 17 from the above example from their site, but I can't seem to get their example to work at all:

```
b'\x00\x0f\x1f\x16\xd1\xcd\x00\xc0\xf0y\x9a\xfd\x08\x00E\x00\x00\x1c\xb1\xce\x00\x006\x01N\xf7\xc0\xa8\x01d\xc0\xa8\x01g\x08\x00\xd9\xd7\xb7\xc4fc'
```

I haven't had any luck converting this string into a human readable object.  No combination of `decode`, `binascii` or anything else I've tried has worked.  Am I using this library incorrectly?

Comment: What happens if you don't open the file in `rb` mode?

Comment: Error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: And to backstep, the output in python2 doesn't appear to be correct either.  I thought maybe it was an issue with WSL2, but it's doing it on my Ubuntu VM as well.  Same issue.

Comment: What do you mean? The output is different than what you shared above?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I commented before I fixed the question.  The question is now updated.  I put the output before that was copy pasted from multiple example sites.  I'm updating the question as I try more solutions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular library, could you share any necessary code and data so that I can run the program myself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203205/discussion-between-truecameltype-and-alexander-cecile).

Answer (score 3):

One of the major differences between python2 and python3 is that in python3, `str` and `bytes` are no longer the same. Compare:

```
$ python2 -c 'print(b"foo" == "foo")'
True

$ python3 -c 'print(b"foo" == "foo")'
False
```

This explains why you must open the file with `"rb"` in python3. (Although it's quite likely that you would get bogus results if you didn't do so on some platforms with python2, because without the `b` line endings that happen to exist in the file may get expanded inappropriately.)

Another difference: in python3, `print` is a function, not a statement so the code you've shown above for python3 is actually a syntax error. Instead you need `print(eth)`

To answer your actual question: When you simply print `eth`, you are implicitly asking the `eth` object to make itself printable. That is the same as calling `print(str(eth))` and so it's giving you a printable string version of the binary data buffer that contains the ethernet frame.

You need to use the facilities of `dpkt` to discover, then dissect the parts of the frame that you care about.

Here's a short example that decodes a pcap containing DNS packets:

```
import dpkt
with open("/tmp/dns.pcap", "rb") as f:
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
    for ts, buf in pcap:
        l2 = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
        print("Ethernet (L2) frame:", repr(l2))

        if l2.type not in (dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP, dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP6):
            print("Not an IP packet")
            continue
        l3 = l2.data
        print("IP packet:", repr(l3))

        if l3.p not in (dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP, dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP):
            print("Not TCP or UDP")
            continue

        l4 = l3.data
        print("Layer 4:", repr(l4))

        if l4.dport in (53, 5353) or l4.sport in (53, 5353):
            dns = l4.data
            if not isinstance(dns, dpkt.dns.DNS):
                dns = dpkt.dns.DNS(dns)
            print("DNS packet:", repr(dns))
```

As for why your output looks different than the tutorial. The tutorial is out of date. Apparently at some point, the implementation of the `__str__` magic method on the `dpkt` objects changed (when you just `print` an object, you get the result of its `__str__` method).

Originally, `__str__` returned a formatted representation of the object. Later it just returns a string representation of the raw bytes of the object. So now you need to call `repr(obj)` in order to get the formatted representation.

Answer (score 0):

try open the pcap-file as binary
'with open('test.pcap','rb')'